# Document-based app where the top-level document represents the window, not tab

Tags: macos, cocoa, document, appkit

When I use Xcode 12 to create a "Document App", the app template that is generated is one where the CoreData-backed "Document" represents the current *tab*, as seen below:

[image]

So basically if I hit cmd-S, the semantics are the to save the content of that one currently-active tab.

However, what if I wanted the "Document" to represent *all* the tabs in that window? Given that these default window tabs are sort of baked in, is Cocoa flexible enough to fit my design criteria?

Comment: What does a tab become when it’s dragged away to form a new window? A new document or still the same one? Are all the tabs different views on the one document. This blog might help with mechanics https://christiantietze.de/posts/2019/01/programmatically-add-nswindow-tabs/

Comment: @WarrenBurton if a tab is dragged away form a window to a new window, it should be come its own new Document. And no, each tab represents a "part" of the Document that is represented by the window the tab resides in. I wonder if this is possible to do, but it's exactly what I require. So it you drag a tab from one window to another, you remove it from the first document and add it to the second.

The linked resource (and follow-up posts) looks like great reading, thanks. I will take a look.

Comment: I think it is possible to drag window tabs between documents but do you want to support undo, versions, state restoration and/or other bells and whistles?

Comment: @Willeke if possible yes, but I understand if I don't get this stuff out of the box with my particular requirements. I'm guessing I could somehow add such functionality myself manually. Any tips on getting the initial functionality working?

Answer (score 1):

The sample you've posted contains **multiple** documents (*Untitled*, *Untitled 2*, ..) inside a single window. Each of these tabs is a separate document with the tabbed interface handled transparently by macOS.

If you'd like to use tabs **inside** a **single** document - like e.g. sheets in a Numbers document - you'd have to implement that functionality on your own.

Comment: Yes so that's what I'm asking. It seems that way to me as well, but on the other hand, Cocoa's default tab handling is really nice (supports reordering, even dragging to open in a new window). So it would be a real shame to need to re-implement all of that myself (and probably worse). Are you 100% that this is the case?

Comment: Tab view in a document-based app is built specifically for handling tabbed documents. You absolutely need to build your own system for using tabbed views inside the document itself.

Answer (score 0):

When a window tab is moved, the `tabGroup` property of the window changes. The `tabGroup` property is observable but this is not documented. Window controllers can be moved to another document with `addWindowController`. I don't know how to prevent a new document from opening in a tab in another document. Accessing the `tabGroup` seems to work but it's a hack. Switching `NSWindow.allowsAutomaticWindowTabbing` off and on also seems to work. Here's my test app (Xcode app template, document based, XIB. Add a WindowController subclass and change the class of the file's owner in Document.xib.)

```
class Document: NSDocument {

    var documentData: [String]? // String per window

    func addWindowTab(_ data: String?) {
        let windowController = WindowController(windowNibName: NSNib.Name("Document"))
        if let text = data {
            windowController.text = text
        }
        if let otherWindowController = windowControllers.first, // document has other window(s)
            let tabgroup = otherWindowController.window?.tabGroup,
            let newWindow = windowController.window {
            tabgroup.addWindow(newWindow)
        }
        else {
            _ = windowController.window?.tabGroup   // access tabGroup to open new documents in a new window
            windowController.showWindow(self)
        }
        addWindowController(windowController)
    }

    override func makeWindowControllers() {
        if let data = documentData {
            for windowData in data {
                addWindowTab(windowData)
            }
        }
        else {
            addWindowTab(nil)
        }
    }
    
    func windowControllerDidChangeTabGroup(_ windowController: NSWindowController) {
        var destinationDocument: Document?
        // check if the window is in a tabgroup with windows of another document
        if let tabGroup = windowController.window?.tabGroup,
            tabGroup.windows.count > 1 {
            for otherWindow in tabGroup.windows {
                if let otherWindowController = otherWindow.delegate as? WindowController,
                    otherWindowController.document !== self {
                    destinationDocument = otherWindowController.document as? Document
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // check if this document has other windows
        else if windowControllers.count > 1 {
            destinationDocument = Document()
            NSDocumentController.shared.addDocument(destinationDocument!)
        }
        if let destinationDocument = destinationDocument,
            destinationDocument !== self {
            destinationDocument.addWindowController(windowController) // removes windowController from self
            if windowControllers.count == 0 {
                close()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
class WindowController: NSWindowController {

    var tabObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        tabObservation = window?.observe(\.tabGroup, options: []) { object, change in
            if let document = self.document as? Document {
                // accessing tabGroup can change tabGroup and cause recursion, schedule on runloop
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    document.windowControllerDidChangeTabGroup(self)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func newWindowForTab(_ sender: Any?) {
        if let document = document as? Document {
            document.addWindowTab(nil)
        }
    }
        
}
```